# How do I get jsp variables from another jsp variable?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp

My controller returns a string with html code. This code contains some JSP variables:

```
<a href='/pages/${page.user.username}/${page.id}/deleteComment?commentId=${comment.id}
```

When I try to append it to my JSP with the JavaScript code (also in my JSP)

```
$("#page-content").html("${page.page}");
```

I get HTML like this instead of correct resolved variables:

```
<a href='/pages/${page.user.username}/${page.id}/deleteComment?commentId=${comment.id}
```

How I can handle it?

Comment: Where is your javascript code located ? In your JSP or in a JS file ?

Comment: In jsp file. When i try to append html code from variable directly (instead of using this var) all displayes fine

Comment: Could you post your full code somewhere ?